# Generate number for 49/6 lottery

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I want to generate all possible combination of six number from 49 balls. We can say 49/6 lottery numbers also. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotto_6/49

When we calculate the possible combination of (49 6) and i get 13983816 using MS excels COMBIN formula.

So My question is that does this calculation will generate possible number from 0 to 49 or 1 to 49?

**If not then how can i get possible sequences which does not include 0.**

Comment: Are you also asking for a random number generator to generate these six number pairs? Of course each drawing would be unique. Regards

Answer (score 1):

See [Binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) on Wikipedia. $\begin{pmatrix}49\\6\end{pmatrix}$ is the number of combinations for drawing six numbers out of fourty nine different numbers. In your case, it is the number of ways to choose six numbers from $\{1, 2, ..., 49\}$ without repetitions, i.e. it is the total number of Lotto 6/49 entries. Note, however, the total number of draw results is $43\times\begin{pmatrix}49\\6\end{pmatrix}$ because a seventh bonus number is also drawn.

Comment: so you mean (49 6) = 6 numbers drawn from 1,2,3,4,..,49, right?

Comment: @Avinash:  that is correct.  If you were drawing from 0 through 49, that is 50 numbers, and the calculation would be $50 \choose 6$

Comment: Can i get any logic to generate all possible sequence of (49 6) without 0?

Comment: @Avinash Ross Millikan and user1551 have already given you the answer. ${49\choose 6}=13983816$ is the number of ways to select 6 distinct values from $\{1,2,\dots,49\}$. The value $0$ is not used in this calculation.